# github pages access with username.github.io not same with custom domain

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages, hexo

I used jekyll before and now I want to use hexo to generate my pages.
Well, I changed the username.github.io to jekyll-blog and add a new username.github.io. Now I can see the new blog with username.github.io, But my custome domain oohcode.com still show the old pages. How can I resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove the CNAME file from old repository,
2. add the CNAME file to the new repository,
3. wait some hours

Answer (score 0):

Use your User name which for your github account as your repository name for example if your github account name is abcg create your repository as abcd.github.io

Comment: Isn't OP already doing that?